# Dash to dock has stopped working on Ubuntu 19.04

Tags: gnome-shell, 19.04, gnome-shell-extension, dock

I upgraded Ubuntu from 18.10 to 19.04 few hours ago, and now the 'dash to dock' extension has stopped working.

Any solution for this bug ?

Comment: When I installed Ubuntu 19.04 and dash to dock in my VM, there was some problems with Ubuntu dock and dash to dock. When I rebooted the system Ubuntu dock automatically turned off and dash to dock was turned on. Try rebooting your system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately it looks like there is not any official solution available now, but it is a [reported bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-shell-extension-dashtodock/+bug/1819086) of the new version fo gnome-shell (3.31/3.32). I guess we would need to wait for an update, or use the previous version of gnome-shell.